# what to do with Satan's distractions

Tags: hadith

salwat to everyone!
I just wanted to ask if Satan is always distracting you and not letting you to do what you want to what exactly should we do? I can't keep myself from Satan's bad intentinons

Answer (score 0):

Different scholars have proposed various approaches, but the most effective method is to study, listen to, or remember something about Imam Hussain (A.S.) and the Battle of Karbala when you encounter this problem. This method has a miraculous effect.

> ان الحسین مصباح الهدی و سفینه النجاه
>
> Indeed, Husayn is the beacon of guidance and the ark of salvation.
>
> -Prophet Muhammad (A.S.)

[Husayn, The Ark Of Survival](https://blog.al-islam.org/general/husayn-the-ark-of-survival/)